# AnyLogic selectOutput condition

Tags: conditional-statements, anylogic

I'm simulation a queuing system where customers join one queue called RDQueue with a capacity of 5, and then moves to a different queue called TDQueue when RDQueue is full (reached the capacity).

I used a selectOutput block with RDQueue on the true branch and TDQueue on the false branch with the condition: RDQueue.size()<5

There should be customers going to TDQueue, but when I run this simulation no customers ever go through the false branch.

(for some reason the image of what I've done won't upload)

I have a source with arrival rate of 0.361 per minute and a delay for RD with a delay time: exponential(8.76) minutes.

According to queuing theory, 68.5% of arrival customers should find RDQueue full and go to TDQueue.

TIA

Comment: What you did seems correct... Maybe your RDQueue is never equal to 5 when a new agent arrives? You need to provide more info

Comment: @Felipe I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your delay time is exponential(8.76) the delay time will always be below the rate in which they are coming:

Random sample from exponential distribution: x = log(1-u)/(−λ)

with λ=8.76 and u as a uniform random number, the expected value of your delay time is 0.114 minutes, so your  RDQueue has a probability of being full of nearly 0%

Comment: Thank you! The delay time is supposed to be 8.76 minutes, so I should've used exponential(0.114) instead of (8.76). Not sure how I missed that, thanks again!